# Overloading the + operator to add arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to merge together two sorted lists by overloading the addition operator. I need to traverse through the first and second list only one time and add each element in order to the new list which is then returned. I am getting an error saying that the operator must take zero or one argument, but when I tried one argument that did not work either. Here is my code:

```
  template<class mytype>
OrderedList<mytype> operator+ (const OrderedList<mytype>& a,const OrderedList<mytype>& b)
{
int size = a.size() + b.size();
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
OrderedList<mytype> newList(size);

   while (i < a.size() && j < b.size()) 
   {
        if (a.get(i) <= b.get(j)) 
        {
             newList.list[k] = a.list[i];
              i++;
        } else 
        {
              newList.list[k] = list[j];
              j++;
        }
        k++;

  if (i < a.size())
  {
        for (int p = i; p < a.size(); p++) 
        {
              newList.list[k] = a.list[p];
              k++;
        }
  } else 
  {
        for (int p = j; p < count; p++) 
        {
              newList.list[k] = list[p];
              k++;
        }
  }
}

return newList;
```

}

Comment: can you post the exact (full) error message and the mark the line of the error message?

Comment: "that did not work either" - it would be good to see that attempt too. But now it's not important, because people have solved your problem without seeing that info.

Comment: I updated my code to make operator+ a friend function. Now when I try to add two lists in my main function I get "Truncated to fit against undefined symbol operator+". My list variable is private in the class and now I do not have access to it either so I cannot add new items into the new list.

Comment: It would simplify your code to use the pattern of writing `operator+=` as a member function, and then doing free function `OrderedList<T> operator+(OrderedList<T> a, OrderedList<T> const &b) { return a += b; }`

Answer (score 3):

Binary operators can only be declared with two arguments if they are non-member functions. The use of the scope resolution operator `::` in `OrderedList<mytype>::operator+` says that `operator+` is a member function of `OrderedList<mytype>` but if that is so it cannot take two arguments. The first argument is implicitly a pointer to the current object, the second is the right hand argument.

If the function was declared as a `friend` in `OrderedList<type>` then it is a non-member function, you can define it as:

```
OrderedList<mytype> operator+(const OrderedList<mytype>& a, const OrderedList<mytype>& b);
```

That is, without the scope resolution operator.

If it was declared as a member function (taking the righthand side only), then you define it as:

```
OrderedList<mytype> OrderedList<mytype>::operator+(const OrderedList<mytype>& b);
```

Where the left hand argument is implicitly `this`.

Comment: The first argument is implicitly a reference

Comment: I now defined it as a friend function but now I do not have access to the list variable to add new items into because it is private. I need to be able compare the items in the two given lists and add them into the new list in order.

Comment: @user3370950 How did you declare it as a friend?

Comment: Here is what is looks like in my header file-->                                          friend OrderedList<mytype> operator+  (const OrderedList<mytype>& a, const OrderedList<mytype>& b);

Comment: @user3370950 Make sure the declaration is a template as well with a different template argument name.

Comment: Yes above my class I have --> template<class mytype>
class OrderedList;

template <class mytype>
OrderedList<mytype> operator+  (const OrderedList<mytype>& a, const OrderedList<mytype>& b);

Comment: @user3370950 I need a minimal program that reproduces the error. Post it [here](http://stacked-crooked.com) and send me the link.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to put all of my code into the website so I copy and pasted each file's code and put it in there for you to check out http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1576f2d4fa521cae

Comment: @user3370950 Inside your code you just do `list[j]` without using an object. It can be either `a` or `b`'s `list`. Which is it? Also, as I said you need to declare the friend as a template. Check the change I made here -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bab09c5dd48c2d7c

Comment: @MattMcNabb I can't seem to find a clause on that. Do you know where it can be found?

Comment: The truncation error is gone now. I did not add the <> characters to the operator line in my header file. But now I just do not know how to get access to the list's variables within the operator function. The list you are referring to is b.list[j]. I had a typo.

Comment: @user3370950 What do you mean you don't know how to get access? Please explain. Also, you also had a problem where you're calling `get()` on a `const` object where `get()` is non-const. I've fixed that here -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2573a2d875099037 If this does not solve all the issues please tell me what *exactly* is the problem

Comment: All of the errors have gone away. I really appreciate the help. I just have one question. In the logic for adding new elements to the array. Is calling the OrderedList Objects dot operator. (ex newList.list[i]). List is a private variable and I was not sure if calling upon it to add an element was correct. Elements are not being added to my newList so I think there is an error somewhere

Comment: @user3370950 Create a `insert()` method that adds an element to an array. The user does not need to access `list` directly.

Comment: @0x499602D2 it's in the overload resolution section; the left hand argument is matched as `*this`. Also it follows the usage; you write `a + b`, not `&a + b` .

Comment: I have an insert method. It adds the given elements and then sorts the list. But for this operator overloading I want to do a merge sort in which I go through both the lists being added and compare elements and add the lesser valued one into the new list. Using my insert method to add items into the new list in not effective because I am adding the new element and then traversing the new list to order it. Should I make a new insert method to add elements into the new list?

Comment: @user3370950 Yes, if you think it will be more efficient then you should.

Answer (score 2):

Your current `operator+` is taking `3` arguments. Two explicit and 1 implicit (`this`). So this is not a valid `operator+`. The `0` or `1` argument the compiler is telling you about is the fact that you are writing a **member function**, so a part from `this` you should either:

- take 0 additional arguments (and have unary `operator+`, as in `int x = +a`)
- take 1 additional arguments (and have binary `operator+`, as in `int x = a + b`)

What you want is probably the second. So you can do either of the following:

- replace all occurrences of `a` in the body with `(*this)`
- move that operator out of the class and effectively declare a free function (recommended)